# Log in Parse through Facebook Issue

Tags: android, parse-platform

Parse always remember first Facebook account that i use for Parse Log-In, even if i switch Facebook account in Facebook app to another it always return first Facebook account

This is how i log-in / out

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(this, new FacebookLogInCallback());
```

.

```
private class FacebookLogInCallback extends LogInCallback {

    @Override
    public void done(final ParseUser user, final ParseException exception) {
       //user always first account
    }
}
```

.

```
ParseUser.logOut();
```

What am i missing ?

Thanks

Comment: You have a logOut method in your sample. Did you mean to say that, after logging out, then switching to another Facebook account, Parse still uses the initial credentials when logging in with Facebook again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i found solution myself

```
call ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

before

```
ParseUser.logOut();
```

Comment: `ParseFacebookUtils.getSession()` has been deprecated and not working anymore. I am still looking for a solution if anyone knowing the answer out there is reading it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32754339/parsefacebookutils-how-to-open-facebook-login-dialog-every-time

Answer (score 0):

I think the same should also be done before ParseFacebookUtils.unlink(). Otherwise you will get tied to old account automatically on next link. (Link is very similar to login, the only difference is in permissions requested from FB).